# Adding WaterMark/Overlay to images with SimpleImage Class

Tags: javascript, php, class, watermark

I use SimpleImage php class to manage img on my website.
I want to add a watermark on images with the overlay method :

```
$imageobject->overlay('watermark.png', 'bottom right');
```

The problem is when i add this line i got 500 (Internal Server Error) when it tries to add the watermark :

```
XHR failed loading:
n.apply(e,arguments)})
```

Someone has an idea on how can i make it work
Thanks to all of you

Comment: You need to check your web servers error log to see what the actual error message is and post it in your question (if you can't solve it yourself from the error message). You could also turn on `display_errors` in your PHP environment while you're developing to see the error messages directly on the screen.

Comment: Seems to me like your not add it the correct way.

Comment: I've already check the error_log but nothing in there related to this.

Comment: Then you might be checking the wrong log or one of the error messages you say isn't related to this, actually is.

Comment: Ive found this in the error log, but there is nothing interesting :
109.238.14.27 - - [06/Feb/2019:17:33:53 +0100] "POST /Uploads/upload.php HTTP/1.0" 500 693 "https://www.X.com/submit" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation :

```
<?php

try {
  $image = new \claviska\SimpleImage();
  $image
    ->fromFile('image.jpg')
    ->overlay('watermark.png', 'bottom right')
    ->toScreen();
} catch(Exception $err) {
  echo $err->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Since we have _no idea_ what the OP does before or after the line they posted, we wouldn't know they actually did all those steps correctly or not. The code the OP posted isn't wrong by itself (if I look at this as a reference).

Comment: True, he could be mixing js/php as well, by the looks of it.

Comment: The question is simply too unclear to be answered without wild guesses.